# C# Sender and Receiver clock sync (timeToleranceInSeconds)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server

I am facing a below exception in C# application using .NET 4.5 framework. the server clock is 8 hours behind and for some reason I cant change the server time. I am facing this error. I am very new to dot NET, I might sound naive.

```
An error was discovered processing the <Security> header ---> WSE065: Creation time of the timestamp is in the future. This typically indicates lack of synchronization between sender and receiver clocks. Make sure the clocks are synchronized or use the timeToleranceInSeconds element in the microsoft.web.services3 configuration section to adjust tolerance for lack of clock synchronization.
```

After some research I found that adding below lines of code might help.

```
<configSections>
     <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>

<microsoft.web.services3>
    <tokenIssuer>
       <ttlInSeconds value="900000" />
    </tokenIssuer>
    <security>
       <defaultTtlInSeconds value="9000000" />
      <timeToleranceInSeconds value="9000000" />
    </security>
<web.services3>
```

But this has resulted in an error I dont understand. [Exception in Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmEkA.png)
I am not sure if I have to add anything in the code as well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2 things, from my understanding that your server time is not syncing with the current time, why do not you sync your server time using the command line w32tm /resync or something similar and run a scheduled job in windows to sync the time every day? you do not need to sync time in .net for your application, the server needs to have a time sync.

With that said, not sure what you are attempting, but assuming time sync might require administrative privilege.

Comment: The server is in US timezone and it is invoked from Europe time. The API request immediately fails because of request timeout, which is a few seconds by default. using above example I tried to increase the timeout time with property timeToleranceInSeconds but gives some errors.  If I change the server time then some other apis fails which are expecting the USA timezone. I know its a bad design but I need to find a solution other than changing the server time.

Comment: I got your point, hope someone can add something more. This is one of that patch (plaster) solution scenarios .

Comment: <microsoft.web.services3> This tag was not already in the config file. Do I have to add something in the code or download something to make it work ?